I am Pakistani. Do I need a transit visa for Athens if I have a Canadian PR Card and US visa?
I have a flight next week that stops in Athens for ~2 hours. My destination is Toronto. I have a Pakistani passport and I read that since it's a third country, generally we require a transit visa in any EU airport.
Will having a Canadian PR card and US visa help me go through the layover without a transit visa?

@Traveller I read it and it did not answer it for me, but here is another duplicate even more specific to Pakistan: Do I need an Airport transit visa /travelling through Greece?
